# How do I count data from 2 different tables by date

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I have 2 tables with no relations, both tables have different number of columns, but there are a few columns that are the same but hold different data. I was able to create a function or view of only the data I wanted, but when I try to count the data by filtering the date, I always get the wrong count in return. Let me explain by showing the 2 functions and what I try to do:

Function 1

```
ID - number from 1 to 8
data sent - YES or NO 
Date - date value
```

Function 2

```
ID - number from 1 to 8
data sent - yes or no
date - date value
```

Upon running both separately, I get all the rows from the tables and everything looks good.

Then I try to add the following to each function:

```
select 
     count([data sent]), ID 
from function1 
Where (date between @date1 and @date2) 
group by ID
```

The above statement works great and gives me the right result for each function.

Now I thought what if I want to add those 2 functions into one and get the count from both functions on 1 page.

So I created the following function:

Function 3

```
select 
    count(Function1.[data sent]) as Expr1, 
    Function1.id, 
    count(Function2.[data sent]) as Expr2, 
    Function1.date
from 
    Function1 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    Function2 on Function1.id = Function2.id
Where 
    (Function1.date between @date1 and @date2)
group by 
    Function1.id
```

Upon running the above, I get the following table:

```
ID  Expr1  Expr2
```

On both Expr1 and Expr2, I get results which I am not sure where they come from. I guess something is being multiplied by 100000 since one table holds almost 15000 rows and the other around 5000 rows.

What I would like to know first is if it possible at all to be able to filter by date and count records from both table at the same time. If anyone need more information please let me know and I will be glad to share and explain more.

Thank you

Comment: You have mentioned that there is no relation between tables, so what is with the join on the `id` field?

Answer (score 0):

The `LEFT OUTER JOIN` is taking each row of the left table, finding ALL of the rows in the right table with the same `id` field, and creating that many rows in the result table.  Since `id` isn't what we usually think of as an identity field (it looks more like a "deviceId" or something), you'll get lots of matches for each one.  Repeat 15000 times and you get your combinatorial explosion.

Tip: To debug things like this, you can create sample tables with a tiny subset of the real data, say 10 rows from each, and run your query on them.  You'll see the issue immediately.

It's possible to filter by date.  It's hard to recommend an actual solution without better understanding your phrase "I want to add those 2 functions into one and get the count from both functions on 1 page".

Comment: OK let me try rephrase it - each funcation has an output i want to take the output resualt from funcation1 and the output resualt from funcation2 and put them toghter into one table, which will be filtered by the date field between 2 dates and count how many yes or no i have in the data sent field. your right about the id field, it is not identity field, lets think of it as a text field. I know where is my problem, when i do count and filter by date it will bring recoreds from both but the date is not been filtered on the funcation2 it just output any row that has the same id field.

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you create a temporary table for each function then join them together?

Comment: I try to do it -  same resualt.

Comment: i do not have any unique fields that has the same data, so any join i try to make is just does not make it right. i try to create a view of both funcation without filter them it pull all the data but when i try to create a new funcation to filter the view it return the same resualt since i have 2 fields of each coulmn and none of these fields match to each other.

Comment: fun1Sent   fun1id  fun1date fun2id fun2sent    fun2date


Extended   7       2/19/2007 5 On time     12/1/2009
Extended   7       2/19/2007 5      12/30/2009
Extended   7       2/19/2007 5 On time     11/16/2010
Extended   7       2/19/2007 5 On time     3/9/2011
Extended   7       2/19/2007 5 On time     3/12/2012
Extended   7       2/19/2007 3 On time     3/1/2010  this is output of both funcation togther top 10 rows

Comment: This might be a job for a stored procedure. You can writte the procedure to filter the date and count the results.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe subqueries can help you to achieve what you want:

```
SELECT
  ID   = COALESCE(f1.ID,   f2.ID),
  Date = COALESCE(f1.Date, f2.Date),
  f1.Expr1,
  f2.Expr2
FROM (
  SELECT
    ID,
    Date,
    Expr1 = COUNT([data sent])
  FROM Function1
  WHERE Date BETWEEN @date1 AND @date2
  GROUP BY
    ID,
    Date
) f1
FULL JOIN (
  SELECT
    ID,
    Date,
    Expr2 = COUNT([data sent])
  FROM Function2
  WHERE Date BETWEEN @date1 AND @date2
  GROUP BY
    ID,
    Date
) f2
ON f1.ID = f2.ID AND f1.Date = f2.Date
```

This query also uses full (outer) join instead of left join, in case the right side of the join contains rows that have no match in the left side (and you want those rows).

Comment: thanks it look like what i have look for i will try it and see if it work. Thanks again.

Comment: ok i get some error message if you can please tell me why i will appreacite it. first i want to ask you if by f1 and f2 you mean funcation1 and funcation2? if yes i get the following error - Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 16
Incorrect syntax near '.'.  Thank you

Comment: `f1` and `f2` are aliases for the subselects that precede them (`f1` for the subselect from `Function1` and `f2` for the subselect from `Function2`). I didn't get any errors in my tests, sorry. Could you perhaps try to find out and tell me where *exactly* does the error occur? For there are many `.`s in this query.

Comment: ok I made a little mistake so i fix it and now it bring the following err - Msg 216, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Parameters were not supplied for the function 'function1'.

Comment: @EZ2010: Well, to be honest, I'm a bit surprised. There's not a word about parameters in your question, and your query examples use `Function1` and `Function2` only as tables or views, not as table-valued functions apparently. So, I'm sorry but presently I don't have enough information to help you with this. The only thing is clear: if the error message says you didn't supply parameters for the function, then apparently you must supply them.